# Stripped screw on fiberglass electrical box

Tags: electrical, screws, junction-box, fiberglass

I made the never-again mistake of using a few fiberglass electrical gang boxes on my recent remodel. It seemed like fiberglass would be better than the plastic boxes, but I learned my lesson there, I now have stripped screw holes on damn near every one. I will always use metal gang boxes from now on, for this reason. But what is the best hack to fix the screw holes on the fiberglass boxes? I don't want to swap them out.

Comment: Epoxy might work in the hole.  Drill it out and drive the screw in.  I would stop driving when the screw gets tight.

Comment: Don't use a power screwdriver, use  manual one, ya know, by hand.

Comment: I don’t know if this applies to your situation, but squish all the wires in before you set the receptacle. Using screw power to compress everything behind isn’t a winning approach.